# foldingStartMarker for log file

Tags: json, syntax, textmate

I am writing a Sublime Text syntax for a certain type of log file.
This is how it looks like:

```
13:56:06 05/27/2014 Executing script of project 'test'.
13:56:06 05/27/2014 yada yada
13:56:06 05/27/2014 Finished executing script of project 'test'.
```

How can I get that part to fold in to one line?

```
"foldingStartMarker": ".*(Executing script of project).*",
"foldingStopMarker": ".*(Finished executing script of project).*",
```

This is my attempt, but it doesn't do much.. Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me in TextMate as a Settings file in a bundle:

```
{   foldingStartMarker = '.*(Executing script of project).*';
    foldingStopMarker = '.*(Finished executing script of project).*';
}
```

I then scoped it to the Language Grammar of that bundle.

Anyways, are you sure that Sublime Text supports that aspect of the TextMate syntax? [The docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html?highlight=foldingstartmarkers) seem to suggest that it doesn't:

> **foldingStartMarker**
>   Currently ignored. Used for code folding.
>   **foldingStopMarker**
>   Currently ignored. Used for code folding.